# Ctrl-arrow does not work in urxvt when using the tabbed extension

Tags: bash, rxvt

When using urxvt with customizations from various sources, Ctrl-Left and Ctrl-Right no longer work for moving between words in for example bash and vi. The cause is not the typical missing keysym lines in `.Xresources` as suggested in other answers, as those exist in the file, and work for other key combinations.

```
URxvt.keysym.Control-Up:    \033[1;5A
URxvt.keysym.Control-Down:  \033[1;5B
URxvt.keysym.Control-Left:  \033[1;5D
URxvt.keysym.Control-Right: \033[1;5C
```

In fact, when doing a `read` or `cat -v` at the terminal, `^[[1;5A` is (correctly) printed for Ctrl-Up, but nothing is printed for Ctrl-Left and Ctrl-Right which instead make the terminal blink. This indicates that the key combination is actually captured before being sent to the terminal.

When using an empty `.Xresources` files, Ctrl-Left/Right are sent to the terminal as expected. What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Does not immediately solve your issue, but avoiding `Ctrl-Left` and `Ctrl-Right` in bash/vi would be a winning strategy in the long run (using the keyboard arrows moves one hand away from its optimal position).  In bash, substitutes are `Alt-F` and `Alt-B`; in vi's command mode, `w` and `b`.

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out, the culprit is the `tabbed` common Perl extension. `tabbed` is clobbering Ctrl-Left/Right for moving the current tab left or right respectively. Simply removing tabbed from the `URxvt.perl-ext-common` fixes the problem, but of course also removes the tab functionality.

In the end, my solution was to create a local copy of `tabbed` extension and using that instead of the default version. First you may want to find your system's copy of `tabbed` and copy it to your local extension directory. On my 64 bit Ubuntu 18 system, the file was located at the location in the `cp` command below. This command of course assumes `~/.urxvt/ext/` already exists.

```
cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/urxvt/perl/tabbed ~/.urxvt/ext/
```

To load the local copy instead of the system copy, remove `tabbed` from the `URxvt.perl-ext-common` (which would load the default version) and add the following line.

```
URxvt.perl-ext: tabbed
```

In `~/.urxvt/ext/tabbed` find the function `tab_key_press` and change it for example as follows:

```
sub tab_key_press {
   my ($self, $tab, $event, $keysym, $str) = @_;

   if ($event->{state} & urxvt::ShiftMask && !($event->{state} & urxvt::ControlMask) ) {
      if ($keysym == 0xff51 || $keysym == 0xff53) {
         my ($idx) = grep $self->{tabs}[$_] == $tab, 0 .. $#{ $self->{tabs} };

         --$idx if $keysym == 0xff51;
         ++$idx if $keysym == 0xff53;

         $self->make_current ($self->{tabs}[$idx % @{ $self->{tabs}}]);

         return 1;
      } elsif ($keysym == 0xff54) {
         $self->new_tab;

         return 1;
      }
   }elsif ($event->{state} & urxvt::ControlMask && $event->{state} & urxvt::ShiftMask) {
      if ($keysym == 0xff51 || $keysym == 0xff53) {
         my ($idx1) = grep $self->{tabs}[$_] == $tab, 0 .. $#{ $self->{tabs} };
         my  $idx2  = ($idx1 + ($keysym == 0xff51 ? -1 : +1)) % @{ $self->{tabs} };

         ($self->{tabs}[$idx1], $self->{tabs}[$idx2]) =
            ($self->{tabs}[$idx2], $self->{tabs}[$idx1]);

         $self->make_current ($self->{tabs}[$idx2]);

         return 1;
      }
   }

   ()
}
```

This version of the function will make Ctrl-Shift-Left/Right move tabs left and right instead of Ctrl-Left/Right. But another possibility is to remove the code for moving tabs left and right altogether and live without that functionality. This would be done by removing the line

```
if ($keysym == 0xff51 || $keysym == 0xff53) {
```

and the following lines to the end of the clause.

Comment: Great answer. (On my Arch system the files were in `/usr/lib/urxvt/perl`.) But with the newer `tabbed-ex` extension, this can also be solved by disabling all `tabbedex` shortcuts with `URxvt.tabbed.no-tabbedex-keys: true`.